# Python Reddit API JSON issues (no PRAW)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I am trying to obtain replies to the comments on Threads. Here is what I have been able to accomplish by parsing JSON:

```
subreddit =  'wallstreetbets'
link = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/r/'+subreddit+'/hot'
hot = requests.get(link,headers = headers)
hot.json()
```

Here is output

```
{'kind': 'Listing',
 'data': {'after': 't3_x8kidp',
  'dist': 27,
  'modhash': None,
  'geo_filter': None,
  'children': [{'kind': 't3',
    'data': {'approved_at_utc': None,
     'subreddit': 'wallstreetbets',
     'selftext': '**Read [rules](https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/wiki/contentguide), follow [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Official_WSB) and [IG](https://www.instagram.com/official_wallstreetbets/), join [Discord](https://discord.gg/wallstreetbets), see [ban bets](https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/wiki/banbets)!**\n\n[dm mods because why not](https://www.reddit.com/message/compose/?to=/r/wallstreetbets)\n\n[Earnings Thread](https://wallstreetbets.reddit.com/x4ryjg)',
     'author_fullname': 't2_bd6q5',
     'saved': False,
     'mod_reason_title': None,
     'gilded': 0,
     'clicked': False,
     'title': 'What Are Your Moves Tomorrow, September 08, 2022',
     'link_flair_richtext': [{'e': 'text', 't': 'Daily Discussion'}],
     'subreddit_name_prefixed': 'r/wallstreetbets',
     'hidden': False,
     'pwls': 7,
     'link_flair_css_class': 'daily',
     'downs': 0,
     'thumbnail_height': None,
     'top_awarded_type': None,
     'hide_score': False,
     'name': 't3_x8ev67',
...
     'created_utc': 1662594703.0,
     'num_crossposts': 0,
     'media': None,
     'is_video': False}}],
  'before': None}}
```

I then turned it into a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for post in hot.json()['data']['children']:
    df = df.append({
        'subreddit' : post['data']['subreddit'],
        'title': post['data']['title'],
        'selftext': post['data']['selftext'],
        'created_utc': post['data']['created_utc'],
        'id': post['data']['id']

      

    }, ignore_index = True)
```

With this, I  was able to obtain a data frame like this[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55uO1.png)

Then, to obtain the comments, I created a list with all the JSON script from the 26 posts, and then created a while loop to iterate through the json script.

```
supereme = len(list_of_comments)
indexy = pd.DataFrame()
while supereme > 0:
    supereme -= 1
    for g in range(0,len(list_of_comments[supereme]['data']['children'])-1):
        indexy = pd.concat([indexy, pd.DataFrame.from_records([{
     'body': list_of_comments[supereme]['data']['children'][g]['data']['body'],
     'post_id': list_of_comments[supereme]['data']['children'][g]['data']['parent_id'] }])], ignore_index = True)

      

  
indexy
```

This gave me this: [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooija.png)
However, I am not able to obtain the replies to the comments. Any help? I tried to do this

```
posts = 26 
for i in np.arange(0,27):
    print('i',i)
    if len(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children']) == 0:
        continue
    for j in np.arange(0,len(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children'])):
        if len(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']) == 0:
            break
        else: 
            print('j',len(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']))
            for z in np.arange(len(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'])):
                if len(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children']) == 0:
                    break
                print('z',z)


                print(list_of_comments[i]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'][z]['data']['body'])
```

The first loop kinda works but it doesn't count up properly to get all the replies to all the posts itll only pull like one or two. We don't want to use PRAW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=len(list_of_comments)
replies = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(list_of_comments)):
    try:
        for j in range(0, len(list_of_comments[x]['data']['children'])):  
            try: 
                for z in range(0, len(list_of_comments[x]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'])):
                    #print(list_of_comments[x]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'][z]['data']['body'])
                    #print(list_of_comments[x]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'][z]['data']['link_id'])
                    replies = pd.concat([replies, pd.DataFrame.from_records([{
        'body': list_of_comments[x]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'][z]['data']['body'],
        'post_id': list_of_comments[x]['data']['children'][j]['data']['replies']['data']['children'][z]['data']['link_id']

      

    }])], ignore_index = True)
                    
            except:
                pass
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?